# SQL sum output based on multiple values

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I get an output that shows the `sum(hours)` for multiple names in this table with one sql command?

Ideal output would for example  (20, 70) based on the below table  which would be the sum hours for each person on that date.

Current SQL.

```
SELECT sum(hours) from project_time where date = '04/07/2013' AND name = 'Rhys Parker'
```

The above sql give the result I want but its only for one users, I would like to get the output for all users on that date.

DB table:

[image: db table]

DB Structure: SQLITE

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_TIME ( name VARCHAR(16), date DATE, project VARCHAR(16), hours VARCHAR(16), PRIMARY KEY (name, project, date))
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` your names and possibly your date, if you want all of them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. All working now. Uptick for all answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, sum(hours) 
FROM project_time 
WHERE date = '04/07/2013' 
GROUP BY name
```

This will get you the sum of hours for each name:

```
Rhys Parker 70
Bob Smith   20
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/97a21/1)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want the name, just the hours, so I removed the "name," and it worked perfectly. Bloody brilliant mate. Cheers for the quick response.

Comment: @Rhys -- no problem, glad we could help!

Answer (score 3):

You will add a `GROUP BY`. Using the aggregate function along with the `GROUP BY` will give you a result for each DISTINCT name you have the in the table:

```
SELECT name, sum(hours) TotalHours
from project_time 
where date = '04/07/2013'
GROUP BY name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cc582/4)

Answer (score 2):

You want a group by:

```
SELECT name, sum(hours)
from project_time
where date = '04/07/2013'
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alternative, if you want it for all the dates, do

```
  SELECT name,date, sum(hours) as TotalHours
   from project_time 
    GROUP BY name,date;
```